# subsection head color

Tags: sectioning, color, sectsty

I can change the colors of the `chapter`, `section` and `subsection` heads, but this manner doesn't change the color of `subsection*` heads.
Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{red}}
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
We will prove ..
\subsection{My subsection}
The sequence is a list..
\subsubsection*{Star Subsection}
We can ...
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Despite its name, your "Star Subsection" is not a subsection, but a sub**sub**section. So to change the colour, you'll need `\subsubsectionfont{\color{red}}` (or just use `\allsectionsfont{\color{red}}` to change all headings at once):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\color{red}}
\sectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsectionfont{\color{red}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{red}}
%\allsectionsfont{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
We will prove ..
\subsection{My subsection}
The sequence is a list..
\subsubsection*{Star Subsection}
We can ...
\end{document}
```

[image]